# How to add product to category and term in brand taxonomy Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Iam using woocommerce Plugin and i created a taxonomy called "brand"
I am creating products manually and i need to set product category and brand .. iam using the below code but its not working in adding categories or brands

```
 $post = array(
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => "publish",
        'post_title' => $product_name,
        'post_parent' => '',
        'post_type' => "product",
        //'post_category' => 17,  // Not working after un comment it

    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error );
    wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, '17', 'brand', true);
    wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, '22', 'product_cat', true);
```

Product created without assigning to any brand or category how can i fix it ?
i ALso tried

```
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'electronics', 'product_cat' );
```

and tried

```
wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, 'electronics', 'product_cat' );
```

But both not working too

Answer (score 0):

`wp_set_post_categories` doesn't accept custom taxonomy, it will save to regular post category https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_categories/#source

This works for saving into Woocommmerce category, I just used it for my needs. Be sure to check that params are integers, not strings like so "10"

```
$product_id = 10;
$product_category_id = 25;
wp_set_object_terms($product_id, array($product_category_id), 'product_cat')
```